# Read XML from a service - Why XML is converted to JSON automatically

Tags: python, json, xml, web-services

Just a why question, I try to find the answer in the documentation, but I don't see it.

I have this code to read an XML from a public web service.
But why when I print the response it is not in XML, but in JSON format. 
Why this happens?

If we go to the source in the browser, we can see it in an XML format.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

var_url = urlopen('https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados?ordem=ASC&ordenarPor=nome')
xml_response = var_url.read()
xml_response = xml_response.decode('utf-8')
var_url.close()

print(xml_response)
```

Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using XML at all.

The API used by https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/... is an JSON API.

You can write:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

var_url = urlopen(
    'https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados?ordem=ASC&ordenarPor=nome'
)
response = var_url.read()
response = response.decode('utf-8')
var_url.close()

obj = json.loads(response)
print(obj)
```

You can display the header of your response by using:

```
print(var_url.info())
```

Comment: yes, i did that. but why when i use the link https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados?ordem=ASC&ordenarPor=nome i see the result in xml in the browser?

Comment: Can see: is it the same link?

Comment: yes! the url is in the code, if you take that URL and paste in the browser the result is XML.

Comment: So, the browser is using a different header. Maybe the `Content-Type`. Inspect your page to see what kind of header is sent to the server.

Comment: Thank you, i understand now... content-type is application/xml. we can specify the format, python by default set to json!?